# Rolling back changes in develop branch with the master content

Tags: git

I made a mess in the develop branch and now I want to rollback to the content of the master branch, how can I do that?

```
* develop
  master
```

After the `git branch` command.

Comment: With checkout I will switch, not overwrite the files of develop with the master files.

Comment: @matt Checking out master only solves half the problem. It still leaves the develop branch with the unwanted work.

Comment: @matt - Are you mad? Checkout just switch and it doesn't answer the question. If you realized what you said after 'throw away' might be the answer, but you haven't said how.

Answer (score 1):

Branches in git are just labels pointing at commits.  They're cheap and easy to move around.  Your repository looks like this.

```
A - B - C - D [master] - E - F - G [develop]
```

You want it to look like this.

```
A - B - C - D [master] [develop]
```

There's several ways to accomplish this.  One is to delete develop and remake it.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git branch -d develop`
3. `git checkout -b develop`

Another effectively does the same thing, but it moves develop in one command.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git branch -f develop`
3. `git checkout develop`

I have `branch -f` aliased to `rebranch`.

Comment: I would give you more than one up vote, but have my thank you very much as an appreciation for what you just did.